# How to convert C#'s BitConverter.GetBytes(date.ToBinary()) to Swift

Tags: c#, ios, swift, nsdate

I have to port some C#-Code to Swift. 
Although I can read and convert most of the C#-Code I'm a bit confused on this:

```
byte[] dateBArr = BitConverter.GetBytes(date.ToBinary());
```

Does anyone how this should be in Swift?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tobinary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, Are you able to get an equivilent "ticks" property in swift?  I predict some multiplication in your future.

Comment: did you solve this?  I need to do the same thing as BitConverter.getBytes in swift.

Comment: Yes, I put it here as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I solved it.
This is my solution (Swift 2.0 if IIRC)

```
let dateNumber = NSNumber(double: NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
let ticks = NSNumber(longLong:dateNumber.longLongValue * 10000000 + 621355968000000000)
let dateDataByteArray:[UInt8] = self.toByteArray(ticks.longLongValue)
```

and for the conversion to byteArray

```
func toByteArray<T>(var value: T) -> [UInt8] {
    return withUnsafePointer(&value) {
        Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: UnsafePointer<UInt8>($0), count: sizeof(T)))
    }
}
```